# Compiler optimizing return by reference vs. by value

Tags: c++, c++11

I wanted to understand the specific optimization if any which can be performed by the compiler here .

The two get functions get() return a string by reference and another by value. Map is global in nature.

I want to understand this as it common thing is done, so what will happen in case we have a map of objects or map of maps or very big strings, (not limiting my map to strings only ).  How costly it can get. I can understand most of us know that it's compiler-dependent, but can we have a list of unknowns. It will really help

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> value;

std::string& get(std::string& key) {
    return value[key];
}

std::string get2(std::string& key) {
    return value[key];
}

int main()
{ 
    value.insert(std::make_pair("name","XXXXXXX"));
    std::string keyaa = "name";
    auto new_val = get(keyaa);
    auto new_val2 = get2(keyaa);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you look at the compiled assembly with optimizations turned on?

Comment: @ChrisMM I did but it made very less as in second case it optimizer more then the one where we are returning the refrence

Comment: you shouldnt write your code according to compiler implementation details. But if you do you need to look at your compilers output. Eg with gcc: https://godbolt.org/z/qj49e9Wod

Comment: It is not true that every compiler in the world implements the same exact optimizations as every other compiler. In order to know whether your compiler will optimize anything here, you will need to look at the actual code your compiler produces.

Comment: i remember something about dynamic allocations not being optimized away when in principle they could. Otherwise your code has 0 observable behavior and `int main() {}` does basically the same

Comment: Program for the behavior you want, then tune for performance if it is lacking and you've run a profiler to find the bottlenecks.  In this case `get` lets you modify the global map, while `get2` does not.  You need to decide if you want the caller to be able to manipulate the data store in the map.  If you don't, then `get2` is your solution, regardless of performance concerns.

Comment: @NathanOliver you can't modify map from get() returned value .

Comment: You can modify the contents.  If you have `auto& ret = get("name");`, then you can do `ret = "string now changed";` and the next time you looked up `"name"`, you'd get `"string now changed"`

Comment: ya sure , but in "auto new_val = get(keyaa)" new_val is not a reference type so it's assigned as a value . in current one we can't modify it . was just trying to understand why this doesn't make compiler to throw any possible warning or message.

Comment: This code could really use some const correctness. Could also matter for compiler optimizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the C++ language perspective there is no guarantee that the copy in `get2` will be elided. Mandatory [return value optimization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) covers only *prvalue* operands (i.e. values created in the function call itself). Even the "permitted" optimization doesn't cover pre-existing objects.

So we can only hope that compilers today are smart enough to optimize away the copy, which means we have to test it!

I've rewritten the example slightly to make it maximally easy for the compiler to optimize away the string:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

struct Test {
    std::map<std::string, std::string> value = {{"name", "XXXXXX"}};

    std::string const& get(std::string const& key) {
        return value[key];
    }

    std::string get2(std::string const& key) {
        return value[key];
    }
};

static void TestReturnByReference(benchmark::State& state) {
  Test test;
  std::string key = "name";
  for (auto _ : state) {
    size_t n = test.get(key).size();
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(n);
  }
}

BENCHMARK(TestReturnByReference);

static void TestReturnByValue(benchmark::State& state) {
  Test test;
  std::string key = "name";
  for (auto _ : state) {
    size_t n = test.get2(key).size();
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(n);
  }
}

BENCHMARK(TestReturnByValue);
```

And no, as it turns out nether GCC nor Clang are able to optimize it away entirely:

**GCC 10.2, -O3:** ([link to quick-bench](https://quick-bench.com/q/vjwzKP9Z8sEtxj5JyLUEd0BXNqQ)) - noticeable difference:

[image]

**Clang 11 (libc++), -O3:** - better, but still slower:

[image]

Conclusion: returning an existing string is faster by reference.

---

Note: starting from C++17, you can return `std::string_view` to avoid worrying about this:

```
std::string_view get(std::string const& key) {
    return value[key];
}
```